# How can I calculate interval variance in a series of dates?

Tags: python

I have a list of account numbers and transaction dates. I would like to calculate the variance in transaction dates per account number. So if there are 10 transactions with dates on one account I would like to know the interval variance. For the amounts in the list I calculated several statistics via groupby:

```
df.groupby('AcctNr').agg({'Amount': [np.count_nonzero, np.sum, np.min, np.max, np.std, np.mean], 'Date': [np.min, np.max]})
```

I succeeded in the min and max date per account number but I can't calculate the variance in intervals.

Comment: Refer [How to create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`numpy.var`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.var.html).